# PHP Form Validation white space issue

Tags: php, validation

I am trying to validate a form. I have my code as follows:

```
if(isset($_POST['data'])) {
        $id = $this->input->post('id');
        $action = $this->input->post('action');
        $table = $this->input->post('table');
        $data = $this->input->post('data');

        $out = array();
        $out['id'] = $id;
        $out['error'] = '';
        $out['fieldErrors'] = '';
        $out['data'] = array();
        $out['row'] = $data;


if($action=="create" && $data['display_name'] === '') {
        if (empty($data['display_name']))
        {
           $this->_out['error'] = "Display name is required";
           echo json_encode( $this->_out );
           exit;
        }
    } 
}
```

Now this is working fine if there is no data inserted in the form, but if there is a space (whitespace) it doesn't work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: add one more condition $data['display_name'] == ' ' Note the space here

Comment: $data['display_name'] === '' should be trim($data['display_name'])==''

Comment: Just check for `empty` in the first place, and leave out the check for `=== ''` …

Comment: You can also use trim to get rid op whitespaces.

Comment: just have a look on my answer below

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options to solve this:

Replace all whitespaces with nothing:

```
if (strlen(preg_replace('/\s/', '', $data['display_name'])) == 0)
{
```

Use trim to remove leading and trailing whitespaces:

```
if (strlen(trim($data['display_name'])) == 0)
{
```

Use `str_replace()` to get rid of invalid characters:

```
if (strlen(str_replace(array(' ', "\t"), array('', ''), $data['display_name'])) == 0)
{
```

Use regular expression to validate a name:

```
if (!preg_match('/^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)$/', $data['display_name']))
{
```

Comment: So `empty(trim(..))` is not the way how it expected to work. At least not is all PHP versions.

Answer (score 0):

Just use trim function and check if its empty string:

```
if ($action=="create") {
    if (trim($data['display_name']) == '') {
        $this->_out['error'] = "Display name is required";
        echo json_encode( $this->_out );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have used the ctype_space function below to check for whitespaces

```
if($action=="create" && ($data['display_name'] === '' || ctype_space($data['display_name']))) {
 $this->_out['error'] = "Display name is required";
 echo json_encode( $this->_out );
 exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`===` checks for type as well along with value comparison, using `trim` function on variable containing values would give you expected results.